# Generate template for a PDF form programmatically

Tags: abap

Some retail company has 3 different business units, each of those uses 3 types of price tags:

- `small` tags (6 columns per A4),
- `medium` tags (3 columns per A4),
- `large` (1 column per A4).

Early implementors of the system have created 9 different templates of price tag PDF form for this. So, any change of preferences regarding the outer appearance of price tags will result in modifications of 9 templates, which doesn't look like a good practice.

What I had in mind is to write a function module `Z_COMPOSE_XML` that takes in 2 parameters (business unit, size of price tag) and compose XML-schema for the template and data of PDF form, so that I will have only 1 form template instead of 9. **How can I achieve this?**

Just to be very clear regarding what I want to do:

1. I want to have a single PDF form, `ZSINGLE_FORM`
2. Program for printing price tags out calls FM `Z_COMPOSE_XML` passing two parameters (business-unit, size of price tag)

So, the output of the form will be dynamic:

- if user passes "X" business-unit and `SMALL` size of price tag, FM `Z_COMPOSE_XML` will generate PDF form with 6 columns per A4 with the label "X" for each column
- if user passes "Y" business-unit and `MEDIUM` size of price-tag, FM `Z_COMPOSE_XML` should generate PDF form with 3 columns per A4 with the label 'Y' for each column.

Comment: What you have in mind should you implement and then come back with a concrete issue.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, unfortunately

Comment: Well, you should try. You provided a very concrete list of what you want to do. Just try to do it and if you have any issue while running your code the come back to Stackoverflow. It is after all what it has been created for.

Comment: The only thing I know is `XFA` to build Adobe Forms programmatically (c.f. demo programs in the package `SAXFT`). I know you can import these forms into the Adobe Livecycle Designer, but I don't know if these forms can be incorporated easily into SAP "SFP" objects (look at how abapGit creates the forms). Anyway, it's too much complex to be the right approach. Why don't you use dynamic "price tags" in your single PDF form?

Comment: Why don't you at least combine the three separate layouts into a single one? This would still require updating the three things inside, but at least they are in one place then.

Comment: Sandra, thank you very much for your eagerness to share your expertise and knowledge, you helped a lot. It's good to have such experts like you in our community :)

Comment: @user9695260 so have you solved the task? With Sandra approach or smth other?